# Automatic enumeration after customizing one item (\enumerate)

Tags: enumerate, labels

[image]

I have a numbered list, labeled: (1), (2), ... (see photo)

I would like to have a * after some of those numbers (not all of them), as shown on the photo.

I have done it by using command `\item[(2)*]` (see below), but the program stops to count items at this line and I must set numbers for all following items manually. Is there a way to do this and keep automatic enumerating?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{align=left}
\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}[label={(}\arabic*{)}]
        \item Random text
        \item[(2)*] Random text
        \item[(3)] Random text
        \item[(4)] Random text
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you say that not too many enumerated items get a star affixed to the numbers, you could just execute `\refstepcounter{enumi}` after, say, `\item[(2)*]`, to increment the applicable counter variable. (Aside: the counter variables associated with level-1 through level-4 enumerated lists are called `enumi`, `enumii`, `enumiii`, and `enumiv`.)

Choosing this method will also let you cross-reference any of the items via the usual `\label`-`\ref` mechanism.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{align=left}
\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}[label=(\arabic*), ref=\arabic*]
        \item Random text
        \item[(2)*]\refstepcounter{enumi} Random text \label{item:b}
        \item Random text
        \item Random text \label{item:d}
    \end{enumerate}
A cross-reference to items \ref{item:b} and \ref{item:d}.
\end{document}
```